# What value of δ should I pick?

Tags: calculus, limits

Given $f(x)=\frac{1}{x-1}$, find $δ$, such as if $0<|x-2|<δ$, then $|f(x)-1|<0.01$.

Original problem is below picture:

[image]

From figure or formula $f(x) = \frac{1}{x-1}$ we can get $f(2) = \frac{1}{2-1} = 1$.

Because we need to guarantee $|f(x)-1|<0.01$, now we have know $f(2) = 1$, so we can get $0.99 < f(x) < 1.01$ when x approach 2, namely $0.99 < f(x) = \frac{1}{x-1} < 1.01$ when x approach 2.

Convert a decimal into a fraction, we can follow these steps:

$\frac{99}{100} < \frac{1}{x-1} < \frac{101}{100}$, so we can get two  inequality: $\frac{99}{100} < \frac{1}{x-1}$ and $\frac{1}{x-1} < \frac{101}{100}$.

Solve the first inequality $\frac{99}{100} < \frac{1}{x-1}$, multiply both sides of an inequality by $\frac{100}{99}$, we can get $\frac{99}{100}\cdot\frac{100}{99} < \frac{1}{x-1}\cdot\frac{100}{99}$, so we get $1 < \frac{1}{x-1}\cdot\frac{100}{99}$, namely $1 < \frac{100}{99\cdot{(x-1)}}$, so we can get $100 > 99\cdot{(x-1)}$.

Now we can get $100 > 99\cdot{x} - 99$, namely $199 > 99\cdot{x}$, solve $x < \frac{199}{99}$.

Solve the second inequality $\frac{1}{x-1} < \frac{101}{100}$ by above approach that we can solve $x > \frac{201}{101}$.

The final range of values for x is $\frac{201}{101} < x < \frac{199}{99}$.

Because we need to find δ that it is related to $0<|x-2|<δ$. so $\frac{201}{101} -2  < x-2 < \frac{199}{99} -2$.

Taking the absolute value of the inequality yields $|\frac{201}{101} -2| < |x-2| < |\frac{199}{99} -2|$, namely $|\frac{201-202}{101}| < |x-2| < |\frac{199-198}{99}|$, so we get $|\frac{-1}{101}| < |x-2| < |\frac{1}{99}|$ or $|\frac{1}{101}| < |x-2| < |\frac{1}{99}|$.

How should I proceed? Take δ = $\frac{1}{99}$?

Comment: As a general rule, $A < B$ does **not** imply $|A|<|B|$. Also, as a general rule in a delta-epsilon exercise, the good values of $\delta$ are always smaller than the bad values of $\delta$.

Comment: @DavidK Thank you for pointing out the issue in my statement. You are right. Such as $-2 < 1$ is not equal to $|-2| < |1|$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As your calculation shows, you need some $\delta>0$ such that
$$|x-2|<\delta\implies \frac{201}{101} -2  < x-2 < \frac{199}{99} -2,$$
i.e.
$$-\delta<x-2<\delta\implies-\frac1{101}< x-2 < \frac1{99}.$$
From this point on, "taking the absolute value of the inequality" is not a good idea. What you want is
$$(-\delta,\delta)\subseteq\left(-\frac1{101},\frac1{99}\right),$$
or equivalently:
$$-\frac1{101}\le-\delta\quad\text{and}\quad\delta\le\frac1{99},$$
i.e.
$$\delta\le\min\left(\frac1{101},\frac1{99}\right)=\frac1{101}.$$